# Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-orm

Creating a spring mvc orm application . There are two controllers namely playerController and TeamController annotated with RequestMapping to perform actions related to these controller.I have used Java configuration for web.xml , dispatcher and for ApplicationContextConfig for defining beans for datasource , sessionFactory and HibernateTransactionManager.Using Mysql database.

On running the application it gives errors -
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Here is WebMvcConfig ->

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.stackroute")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /*
     * Define the bean for view resolver so that it can be used to resolve the JSP
     * files which are existing in /WEB-INF/views folder. A ViewResolver is capable
     * of mapping logical view names to actual views, such as a JSP or a HTML page.
     */

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Here when i give componentScan basepackage as - com.stackroute.model

the app gives error as - No mapping for GET /sa_spring_mvc_orm_assessment/ DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

when i change basePackage to - com.stackroute

the app gives error like -

> Error

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'teamController' defined in file [/Users/vikash/Desktop/Assesment/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sa_spring_mvc_orm_assessment/WEB-INF/classes/com/stackroute/controller/TeamController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'teamServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/vikash/Desktop/Assesment/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sa_spring_mvc_orm_assessment/WEB-INF/classes/com/stackroute/service/TeamServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.stackroute.dao.TeamDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:577)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'teamServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/vikash/Desktop/Assesment/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/sa_spring_mvc_orm_assessment/WEB-INF/classes/com/stackroute/service/TeamServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.stackroute.dao.TeamDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:577)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.stackroute.dao.TeamDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1644)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:577)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Which basePackage i should give?

com.stackroute is the root package and all other classes are in com.stackroute.model
com.stackroute.controller

com.stackroute.config - containg webMvcConfig ApplicationContextConfig and WebAppAppInitialzer

Similarly for dao and service.

Here are the code for my controllers and ApplicationContextConfig

> code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/team")
public class TeamController {

    /*
     *
     * 
     * 1. Display the list of existing Team from the persistence data. Each Team
     * element should contain Team name, Team lead and list of players 2. Add a new
     * team which should contain the Name, Lead 3. Delete an existing team 4. Update
     * an existing team
     * 
     */

    private TeamService teamService;
    
    @Autowired
    public TeamController(TeamService teamService) {
        this.teamService = teamService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
//  @GetMapping(value = "/team")
    public String indexPage(ModelMap model) throws TeamDoesNotExistException{
        Player player = new Player();
        Team team = new Team();
        List<Team> teams = this.teamService.getAllTeams();
        model.addAttribute("teams", teams);
        model.addAttribute("team", team);
        model.addAttribute("player", player);
        return "index";
    }


//  @PostMapping(value = "/team/add")
    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public String addTeam(@ModelAttribute("team") Team newTeam, ModelMap model) {

        if (newTeam.getName().isEmpty() || newTeam.getLead().isEmpty() || newTeam.getPlayers().isEmpty()) {
            
            Player player = new Player();
            Team team = new Team();
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
            model.addAttribute("team", team);
            model.addAttribute("teams", teamService.getAllTeams());
            return "index";
        }

        try {
            teamService.createTeam(newTeam);
            model.addAttribute("team", newTeam);
            model.addAttribute("teamPlayers", newTeam.getPlayers());
        } catch (TeamAlreadyExistException e) {
            model.addAttribute("teamErrorMessage", e.toString());
            return "index";
        }

        return "redirect:/";
//      return "redirect:/team";

    }


//  @PostMapping(value = "/team/update")
    @PostMapping(value = "/update")
    public String updateTeam(@ModelAttribute("team") Team newTeam, ModelMap model) {

        if (newTeam.getName().isEmpty() || newTeam.getLead().isEmpty() || newTeam.getPlayers().isEmpty()) {
            
            Player player = new Player();
            Team team = new Team();
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
            model.addAttribute("team", team);
            model.addAttribute("teams", teamService.getAllTeams());
            return "index"; 
        }

        try {
            teamService.updateTeam(newTeam);
            model.addAttribute("team", newTeam);
            model.addAttribute("teamPlayers", newTeam.getPlayers());
        } catch (TeamDoesNotExistException e) {
            model.addAttribute("teamErrorMessage", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "index";
        }

        return "redirect:/index";
    }

//  @GetMapping("/team/delete")
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteTeam(@RequestParam("name") String teamName, ModelMap model) {

        if(teamName.equals(""))
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            Team team = new Team();
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
            model.addAttribute("team", team);
            model.addAttribute("teams",teamService.getAllTeams());
            return "index";
        }
        
        try {
            teamService.deleteTeam(teamName);

        } catch (TeamDoesNotExistException e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "index";
        }

        return "redirect:/";
//      return "redirect:/team";

    }
    

//  @GetMapping("/team/players")
    @GetMapping("/players")
    public String getTeamPlayers(@RequestParam("name") String teamName, ModelMap model) {

        try {
            List<Player> players = teamService.getAllPlayers(teamName);
            model.addAttribute("teamPlayers", players);
            for (Player player : players) {
                model.addAttribute("team", player.getTeam());
            }
        } catch (TeamDoesNotExistException e) {

            model.addAttribute("teamErrorMessage", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/index";

    }

}



@Controller
@RequestMapping(path= "/player")
public class PlayerController {

    /*
     * 
     * 
     * 1. Display the list of existing Player from the persistence data. Each Player
     * element should contain emailId, name, and details. 2. Add a new player which
     * should contain the emailId, name, and details 3. Delete an existing player 4.
     * Update an existing player
     * 
     */

    private PlayerService playerService;

    @Autowired
    public PlayerController(PlayerService playerService) {
        this.playerService = playerService;
    }

//  @GetMapping("/player")
//  @RequestMapping(value ="player" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String indexPage(ModelMap model) {

        List<Player> players = playerService.getAllPlayers();

        model.addAttribute("teamPlayers", players);

        for (Player player : players) {
            model.addAttribute("teams", player.getTeam());
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
        }

        return "index";
    }

//  @PostMapping(value = "player/addPlayer")
    @PostMapping(value = "/addPlayer")
    public String addPlayer(@ModelAttribute("player") Player newPlayer, ModelMap model)
            throws PlayerAlreadyExistException {
        if (newPlayer.getDetails().isEmpty() || newPlayer.getEmailId().isEmpty() || newPlayer.getName().isEmpty()
                || newPlayer.getName().isEmpty()) {

            Player player = new Player();
            Team team = new Team();
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
            model.addAttribute("team", team);
            return "index";

        }

        try {
            playerService.addPlayer(newPlayer);
            model.addAttribute("player", newPlayer.getTeam());
            model.addAttribute("teamPlayers", playerService.getAllPlayers());
            return "redirect:/";
        } catch (PlayerAlreadyExistException e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "index";
        }

    }



//  @GetMapping("player/delete")
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deletePlayer(@RequestParam("emailId") String emailId, ModelMap model) {

        try {
            playerService.deletePlayer(emailId);
            return "redirect:/";
        } catch (PlayerDoesNotExistException e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "index";
        }

    }

//  @GetMapping("player/get")
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getPlayer(@RequestParam("emailId") String emailId, ModelMap model) {

        try {
            Player player = this.playerService.getPlayer(emailId);
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
            return "redirect:/";

        } catch (PlayerDoesNotExistException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("getPlayerErrorMessage", e.toString());
            return "index";
        }

    }


//  @PostMapping(value = "player/update")
    @PostMapping(value = "/update")
    public String updatePlayer(@ModelAttribute("player") Player newPlayer, ModelMap model) {

        if (newPlayer.getDetails().isEmpty() || newPlayer.getEmailId().isEmpty() || newPlayer.getName().isEmpty()
                || newPlayer.getName().isEmpty()) {
            Player player = new Player();
            Team team = new Team();
            model.addAttribute("player", player);
            model.addAttribute("team", team);
            return "index";
        }

        try {
            playerService.updatePlayer(newPlayer);
            return "redirect:/index";

        } catch (PlayerDoesNotExistException e) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", e.toString());
            return "index";
        }

    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    // Read db properties with @Value annotation and store private variables
    // see the variables names in db.properties file of resources folder.
    // MYSQL_USER
    // MYSQL_PASSWORD
    // MYSQL_DRIVER
    // MYSQL_URL

    @Value("${MYSQL_USER}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${MYSQL_PASSWORD}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${MYSQL_DRIVER}")
    private String driver;

    @Value("${MYSQL_URL}")
    private String url;


    /*
     * Define the bean for DataSource. In our application, we are using MySQL as the
     * dataSource. To create the DataSource bean, we need to know: 1. Driver class
     * name 2. Database URL 3. UserName 4. Password
     */


    @Bean("datasource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean loclSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        loclSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
//      loclSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.stackroute.model" });

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");

        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

//      properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "auto");

        loclSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        loclSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Player.class, Team.class);
        loclSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return loclSessionFactoryBean;

    }



    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getHibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using the outdated setup instead of Spring Boot?

Comment: Its an assignment that requires spring mvc only.

Comment: **assignment that requires spring mvc only** does not mean you can not use SpringBoot to bootstrap the project.